# Error while making ListView inside of Asynctask - Android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask

I have a main activity which extends ListActivity, then inside of that activity is an Asynctask called loadcomments. This Asynctask collects comments with json and returns them into an array, in the doInBackground function, then the onPostExecute places the array into a String[] which places them into a listView. This is my code,

```
    public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity {

    class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


            } 

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            } 

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {


                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);


                    return json2;



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                try {  
                    if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 


                            JSONArray array = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
                            String comments[] = new String[array.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<=array.length(); i++ ) {
                                comments[i] = array.getString(i);
                            }
                            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DashboardActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, comments));







                            }//end if key is == 1
                        else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                        }//end else
                    }//end if
                } //end try

                catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch    
            }
        }


        new loadComments().execute();
```

I have tried this code an it does not work, here is my log cat,

```
    07-08 21:10:51.468: D/AndroidRuntime(26516): Shutting down VM
07-08 21:10:51.468: W/dalvikvm(26516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac9228)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:250)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1885)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at com.example.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:101)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
07-08 21:10:51.478: E/AndroidRuntime(26516):    ... 11 more
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): killProcess, pid=26516
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:788)
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-08 21:10:52.750: D/Process(26516): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error specified the source of the error already:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

To use the ListActivity, the layout you loaded must have the this view:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: I have done this an the app doesnt crash anymore but the comments are not showing up, why is that?

Comment: Try tracing the code execution to make sure the comment are loaded